# Setting spinner value depending on number picked?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner, android-number-picker

I am not sure if this is the right way, I need some help to solve this problem.I want to select a number from the NumberPicker. After selecting, I expect the setOnValueChangedListener to be able to capture the value and run a for loop and store the resulting values in an arraylist. Next, i want the loop values to be displayed in my spinner . But i am getting an error message saying "cannot resolve constructor ArrayAdapter(....)" and when i run the app, i get this error message :

> "Error:(79, 58) error: no suitable constructor found for ArrayAdapter(,int,List)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,List) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,List) is not applicable
>   (actual argument  cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int,Object[]) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,Object[]) is not applicable
>   (actual argument  cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int,int) is not applicable
>   (actual argument  cannot be converted to Context by method invocation conversion)
>   constructor ArrayAdapter.ArrayAdapter(Context,int) is not applicable
>   (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)"

```
      @Override    
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.new_item);
           final List<Integer> resultInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // to store the integer value

   final Spinner hourSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.hourSpinner);


    final NumberPicker HourPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.HourNumberPicker);
    HourPicker.setMinValue(9);
    HourPicker.setMaxValue(15);
    HourPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

    HourPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

            Integer value = HourPicker.getValue();

            for (int index = 0; index == value; index++)
            {
                resultInteger.add(index);
            }

          ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> hourAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, resultInteger);
            hourAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            hourSpinner.setAdapter(hourAdapter);
    }
    });
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Change ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> to " ArrayAdapter<Integer> "

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine now but i am having some issues with the for loop as nothing is showing in my spinner @Ram

Comment: Why that for loop is required?  just add value to resultInteger list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change from `this` to `YourActivity.this`

```
new ArrayAdapter(this, ...)
```

to

```
new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(YourActivity.this, ...)
```

check this code.

```
hourPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            Integer value = hourPicker.getValue();

            resultInteger.clear();
            for (int index = 0; index < value; index++) {
                resultInteger.add(index);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<Integer> hourAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(YourActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, resultInteger);
            hourAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            hourSpinner.setAdapter(hourAdapter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It is working but the for loop is not working. Is there something that i am missing ?

Comment: check @Ram's comment.

Comment: @topacoBoy check the answer.

Comment: Not sure, try using List<String> and convert int to string using String.valueOf(int)

Comment: It is working already. Thank you @dbk for helping me out. Btw, why did you put `ArrayAdapter<>` ?

Comment: you can replace explicit type argument with <>

Answer (score 0):

@topacoboy on scroll you want to add number in spinner? try following code.

```
HourPicker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    HourPicker.setMinValue(9);
    HourPicker.setMaxValue(15);
    HourPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
     resultInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    HourPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {

            Integer value = HourPicker.getValue();

           // for (int index = 0; index == value; index++) {
                resultInteger.add(value);
           //}

            ArrayAdapter<Integer> hourAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, resultInteger);
            hourAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            hourSpinner.setAdapter(hourAdapter);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Remove for loop. add direct before adding in array list check this number list.contain() if number is present then don't add.

Comment: I wanted it to loop the value selected by the user and display it so that is why i needed the for loop. Anyway i got i fixed. Thanks for the help man @RahulWadhai